# How to remove the bottom line of datepicker in android using xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, react-native

I'm using DatePicker control in my xamarin.forms application which shows a bottom line for date picker in android devices but idon't want that line. How can I remove that line??

I've try to remove the line by using some custom renders but it doesn't work. The renderer I've tried to apply is:

```
public class BorderlessDatePickerRenderer:DatePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            Control.Background = null;

            var layoutParams = new MarginLayoutParams(Control.LayoutParameters);
            layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            Control.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the background to empty and it should work:

```
  Control.SetBackgroundResource(0);
```

**Update:**

```
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BorderlessDatePicker), typeof(BorderlessDatePickerRenderer))]
public class BorderlessDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
{
    public static void Init() { }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            Control.Background = null;

            var layoutParams = new MarginLayoutParams(Control.LayoutParameters);
            layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetStroke(0, Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray);
            Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
            Control.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

In case of queries feel free to revert

Comment: ,Thank you for responding.But this property doesn't effect anything in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transparent gradiant into OnElementChanged

```
var gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.SetStroke(0, Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
Control.SetBackground(gd);
```